# Using JavaScript/HTML5/ Canvas Drag & Drop Floor Layout Design in web

Tags: library, javascript, html, diagram

I'm currently working on developing a ASP.NET MVC based application which enables users to have a canvas for dragging and dropping floor and room based images (e.g. Sofas, Tv, Bed, Tables, etc.). Essentially, I want to build something like draw.io but enable the user to come up with a final product like this:

https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=&p=ex1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Floorplan.html#Uhttps%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fa%2Fseibert-media.net%2Fuc%3Fid%3D1as2h_1PqQBNIhRlzLDkm7s6joCD5jxBt%26export%3Ddownload

I'm looking for the best library to carry out the drawing. There are so many JavaScript libraries, but I'm not quite sure which is the most preferred (easiest) for such a task.

Ideally, the left pane would have different svgs that the user can drag onto some canvas (e.g. Sofas, Tv, Bed, Tables, etc.). Then they can connect them to each other, etc.The appropriate library to build such a tool is what I really need advise on!

Comment: Do you also require to be able to define the room layout (it might not be rectangular)? Its dimensions? Connect multiple rooms together?

Comment: I am not quite clear here – are you looking for a totally standalone app to draw & export as SVG, or are you looking for a library to add into your own app?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Syncfusion ASP.NET MVC Diagram library](https://www.syncfusion.com/aspnet-mvc-ui-controls/diagram), it can be easily integrated with an MVC application. Custom shapes and connector can also be defined using SVG or JavaScript.

Example
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/Diagram/DefaultFunctionalities#/material

Comment: Seems to give a choice between FlowChart, MinMap & Org Chart.

Comment: oh, I messed up the link. Actually, the given example is a showcase application that is built using syncfusion diagram library. But the core library supports multiple types. I will edit the example link

Comment: That seems to be a flowchart. It looks nothing like the OP's sample floorplan, and I don't see any way to sad ", Tv, Bed, Tables, etc". Also, although he doesn't make it totally clear, it seems to me that he doesn't want a standalone application, but something that he can add into his own .NET app. Hopefully, he will clarify (if he ever logs in again).

Comment: I've created a simple sample for floor plan [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/221092/ze/MVC_Floor_Planner-1189233668). Hope it helps

Comment: I hope so, but alas the OP hasn't logged in for five months, shortly after he joined & posted this question. I have upvoted you as much as I can for your contribution. Hopefully he will come back one day and accept the answer. Welcome aboard :-)